# Strange behavior of data.table with 'by' argument?

Tags: r, data.table

I just want a function to sum over rows in a data.table overwriting the old values using the `by` argument. Normally I would expect to get in all rows grouped together with `by` the same results. I have created 2 examples. The only difference of the first to the second one is the deletion of the leading 3 digits in the **take** column of the data.table. The first example works as expected, the second shows some unexpected behavior. I would be glad to get any hint of what I'm doing wrong.

R version: 4.0.4

data.table version: 1.14.2

```
library(data.table)

# my expected function
superpose <- function(DT){
  DT <- copy(DT)
  DT[, value := sum(value), by = take]
}

v1a = c(   55:   59,    33:   37,    54:   56,    32:   34,    58:   60,    36:   38)
v1b = c(25555:25559, 20533:20537, 25554:25556, 20532:20534, 25558:25560, 20536:20538)
all.equal(as.integer(factor(v1a)), as.integer(factor(v1b)))
# [1] TRUE

v2 = 1:22

data1 <- data.table(take = v1a, value = v2) # 1st data - expected behavior
data2 <- data.table(take = v1b, value = v2) # 2nd data - unexpected behavior

res1 <- superpose(data1)
res2 <- superpose(data2)

cbind(res1, res2)
which(res1[, value] != res2[, value])
# [1]  8 11 15 16 19 20 21 22
```

Comment: I simplified your example slightly to make it easier for readers to see the issue.  Feel free to revert if you don't like my edits

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. I've replicated it 1000 times, and in all cases `which(.)` is length 0, indicating that all `res1$value` are equal to `res2$value`.

Comment: @r2evans - what data.table version do you have?   I get same issue as OP with data.table 1.14.3 (R 4.1.3, Linux).

Comment: @dww I'm on 1.14.2, curious.

Comment: @r2evans, I can also reproduce this on 1.14.3 / Win 10

Comment: Interestingly, if we do `v1a = as.character(v1a); v1b = as.character(v1b)` then the two results are identical (as they should be).

Comment: Sounds like either a regression, a misunderstanding, or a previous "feature" (bug) recently fixed. @JohnSnider, I suggest you file a [bug report](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/new/choose) with this example.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: @dww you are right to rearrange my code block - thank you! My example is not shorter because I could not find any unexpected results with easier contents.

Yes, I thought also about a workaround with `as.character(va1)`. But for that I would need at the end a retransformation to integer. Or I could define a further column deleting at the end. Both would apparently work but costs additional memory or/and calculation.

Comment: @r2evans I tried it with 1.14.2 and 1.14.3 - both with same result.

Comment: Are you comfortable with opening a bug report as suggested by @r2evans, or should we help?

Comment: @Waldi Thank you for your query. I'm quite a bit confused. Today morning I started my computer and I could not reproduce the described behavior either with version 1.14.2 nor with 1.14.3! What to do now? Should I really write the bug report?

Comment: Is there anyone how can reproduce the behavior and could tell me the choosed seed? I would like to add a `set.seed()` to the example above.

Comment: I suggest that I have used some minor version of 1.14.3 with the bug. After downgrading to 1.14.2 I just overloaded with `library(data.table)` but maybe some of the 1.14.3 kept still in memory? Today the fresh 1.14.2 worked and the renewed installation of 1.14.3 should be some higher minor version without the bug?

Comment: I have submitted a bug report [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5360)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was already an [open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5345) on github relating to this bug in `data.table 1.14.3`.  This has now been fixed in the latest development version, which can be installed using:

```
update.dev.pkg()
```

This is a cautionary tale on why only the brave of heart should use development code - and expect issues to arise if you do.